# How to write multiple line content to any linux filesystem using php ssh exec?

Tags: php, shell, remote-server

Suppose there is a file (**test.txt**) with content.

```
testing php data
employee data
country data
```

I want to write this content in the **/tmp** dir of a remote linux machine. I am using following code

```
 // $con contains all content of the text.txt file
 $con = file_get_contents("C:/wamp/www/test.txt");
 // $ssh is the sshobject for the remote machine
 $ssh->exec('echo "$con" > /tmp/text1.txt');
```

It creates a  empty file on the remote machine. What should I use for make copy of content on remote machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write this code

```
 // $con contains all content of the text.txt file
 $con = file_get_contents("C:/wamp/www/test.txt");
 // $ssh is the sshobject for the remote machine
 $ssh->exec("echo '{$con}' > /tmp/text1.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

check your quotes.

```
$ssh->exec('echo "'.$con.'" > /tmp/text1.txt');
```

$con won't be parsed with  a single quote.